# How do I use Cloud DataStore or Cloud SQL from Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a Firebase app, and plan to use the real-time database when I need real-time updates.  However, most of the application data is more traditional.

Now that Functions is a thing, how do I also leverage either DataStore or CloudSQL?  Can anyone point me to specific documentation or examples how to read/write with either of those services from a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither Cloud Datastore nor Cloud SQL support Cloud Functions yet, which means you aren't yet able to trigger Cloud Functions based on their events the way you can with the Firebase Realtime Database.

Fortunately, once a Cloud Function has been triggered (for example via HTTP), you can still read and write from Datastore and SQL as you would from any other Node.js code. [Here is documentation for Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore), and [here it is for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql).

Finally, if you're adventurous and might like to provide early feedback on upcoming integrations like Datastore, [fill out this form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdW5eSxfWjxATaANrf2aHHlfQ5b1ZH90tfClfYQ5TNblVc2xA/viewform?c=0&w=1)!

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  I'd like to be able to read/write to CloudSQL from an HTTPS-triggered function, that I post to from my Firebase web app. The link you gave is for AppEngine.  Are there any examples for setting up a function to do the same (e.g. config files, package.json, auth to the service, ensuring the call is made by a user that was authed in the app, etc.)

Comment: Good question, I don't think there's sample code for that yet. I've filed a request with the team to create a new entry in [the samples repository](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples). If you figure it out, you're also welcome to contribute one yourself!

Cloud Functions should be able to use mostly the same code that you also use in AppEngine. Note that in the AppEngine instructions there's a proxy for local testing - you won't need that when running a function in Cloud Functions.

Comment: Anyone seeking Cloud SQL support should click the star on the issue tracker.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36388165

Comment: @Robert-JanHuijsman Any features coming in Firebase related to Datastore?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out Firestore: it's the best of both worlds between Datastore and Firebase, including Functions integration. Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/. Nothing to announce for Datastore itself right now.